# ASP.NET - How to remove Newtonsoft.Json dependency

Tags: asp.net, reference, json.net

I added the reference file "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" to my project. After a while, I decided to remove the reference from References section of project. Projects started to give following error :

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried everything. I searched any words with "Newtonsoft" in the project and delete all of them. But nothing changes. I am getting still this error. Can anyone help me? How can I remove this reference forever ?

Comment: if ur project build sucessfully after removed dll ? Try using rebuild-All

Comment: Are you using Web API?  It has a dependency on Json.Net.

Comment: I can build successfully with/withour dll. No I am not using Web API

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The project requires "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0", But I realized that I load the "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0" version. After I add v6 dll file to project, the problem solved. Thanks for your responses.